# User migration to Azure AD with multi-domain

Tags: azure-ad

I want to migrate my users from AD in different domains and merge them to a single AD under my azure cloud.

I tried with one domain (abc.com) and it worked well. However, when I try to merge users from my other domain (xyz.com) into the same AD it doesn't allow a trust between the different domains and gets failed.

Can anyone help in this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's strictly related to Azure AD, and not SharePoint